# Using "bottom" style to position Google Maps overlay

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to replace markers on a Google map using the custom overlay in order to have HTML for each marker. It works except I can't figure out how to have the bottom of the overlay over the point, instead of having the top of the overlay below the point. I've reproduced the error using a super-reduced set of code just for testing (below). Instead of my actual HTML I'm just drawing a red rectangle.

The problem is in the draw function. When I assign div.style.top to the point it works (but not the way I want), but when I switch it to div.style.bottom getting the y value instead it does not work as expected; the red square is not on the map. (In my original program the markers end up being drawn in a vertically-mirrored pattern, and far from the indended locations.)

How can I get assigning div.style.bottom to work the way I want it to?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom Overlay Test</title>
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var overlay;
TestOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.89, -77.03)
    };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  overlay = new TestOverlay(new google.maps.LatLng(38.89, -77.03), map);
  }

function TestOverlay(point, map) {
  this.point_ = point;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
  }

TestOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '5px';
  div.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.width = '200px';
  div.style.height = '50px';
  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  };

TestOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var point = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.point_);
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
  div.style.bottom = point.y + 'px';
  };

TestOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
  };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `div.style.top = point.y-div.offsetHeight + 'px';`

Answer (score 1):

Ta-da; got it. The trick is that `top` and `bottom` differ by more than whether they position the element using its top or bottom; they differ in the direction of the measurement. Both measure from the top of the parent element, but `top` adds to the y-axis, and `bottom` subtracts from the y-axis. So to fix the problem I just needed to reverse the sign of the distance: `div.style.bottom = -point.y + 'px';`